# How to automatically refresh a web page using PHP at a certain time every day?

Tags: php

I need a page to refresh every day at 3 am local time (Thats GMT+4).. any ideas on how to do this with PHP? Using a function maybe?

Comment: Write a script containting `wget`, then add your script to `cron`

Comment: Note that PHP is server-sided, and not client-sided. Refreshing a page at a specific time can be done using the `Refresh` HTTP header + calculating the seconds for the next refresh. For example, `header('Refresh: 40')` refreshes the requested page **in the browser** every 40 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a php code that should make page to refresh at 3:00 each day:

```
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$now = time();
$today = strtotime('3:00');
$tomorrow = strtotime('tomorrow 3:00');
if (($today - $now) > 0) {
    $refreshTime = $today - $now;
} else {
    $refreshTime = $tomorrow - $now;
}

header("Refresh: $refreshTime; url=$page");
```

Maybe operations with time can be further optimized

Answer (score 1):

I presume you need to have (at least one) script running every day at 3am.

You can't do that with PHP alone. Or to clarify - you should not do that with PHP.
Correct solution is to use Cron (Linux environment) or task scheduler (Windows environment), which are designed, to periodically run process on selected time. Than you can request your page via wget/cURL or better yet, if you don`t need web server, run your script directly via PHP (like "[path to php] [path to php script]" which could look like c:\xampp\php c:\xampp\htdocs\myLocalPHPFile.php)

Alternate (wrong) solution is to sleep current process until desired time. The problem is, that you would need to determine the correct time by hand (using date functions), if someone kills your process (i.e. PHP itself with max execution time), than there would be nothing to call that script. Another problem is with multiple instances of that script running - and PHP by itself has no way of knowing if this is the case (of course this can also be solved via locks or better yet via listing all processes and killing another instances of that script).